# Generic XSLT 1.0 to convert XML on some specific node path

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert a XML file to a normalized XML with some selected nodes.
I am saving the node names with their path in a variable like this:

```
  <xsl:variable name="nodePath">
    <path>class/id</path>
    <path>class/title</path>
    <path>class/description_url</path>
    <path>class/duration</path>
  </xsl:variable>
```

XML Sample data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<table>
  <other_node>Ignore</other_node>
  <class>
    <id>Test Data</id>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <description_url>Test Data</description_url>
    <duration>2</duration>
  </class>
  <class>
    <id>Test Data</id>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <description_url>Test Data</description_url>
    <duration>2</duration>
    <other_node>Ignore</other_node>
  </class>
  <class>
    <id>Test Data</id>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <description_url>Test Data</description_url>
    <duration>2</duration>
  </class>
</table>
```

Output:

```
<rows>
  <row>
    <id>Test Data</id>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <description_url>Test Data</description_url>
    <duration>2</duration>
  </row>
  <row>
    <id>Test Data</id>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <description_url>Test Data</description_url>
    <duration>2</duration>
  </row>
  <row>
    <id>Test Data</id>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <description_url>Test Data</description_url>
    <duration>2</duration>
  </row>
</rows>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use EXSLT extensions? http://exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/

Comment: will it be processor dependent?

Comment: Yes, support for EXSLT depends on your XSLT processor. Standard XSLT 1.0 has no means to evaluate strings as XPath expressions.

Comment: My processor is `Apache Xalan`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a solution to the problem as you present it, but you can do something similar. The problematic thing is that you do not really list paths to all elements you'd like to keep, for instance you still need `table` and `class`, even if they are not listed in the variable, the same goes for the text (text is a node, too).

Then your variable contains relative paths, and it is not clear on which level in the input tree they apply. A way around this problem is indicating the level of an expression with a `level` attribute.

Reading path expressions from a variable introduces two difficulties in XSLT 1.0:

- iterating over elements inside an `xsl:variable`, i.e. using it as a result tree fragment, is not possible in standard XSLT 1.0. Use `exsl:node-set()`.
- Standard XSLT 1.0 has no means to evaluate strings as XPath expressions. Use `dyn:evaluate()`.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="dyn exsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="nodePath">
        <path level="1">class</path>
        <path level="2">id</path>
        <path level="2">title</path>
        <path level="2">description_url</path>
        <path level="2">duration</path>
    </xsl:variable> 

    <xsl:template match="/table">
        <xsl:variable name="context" select="."/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($nodePath)/*[@level = '1']">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="dyn:evaluate(concat('$context/',.))"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/table/*">
        <xsl:variable name="context" select="."/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($nodePath)/*[@level = '2']">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="dyn:evaluate(concat('$context/',.))"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/table/*/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
<class>
<id>Test Data</id>
<title>Testing</title>
<description_url>Test Data</description_url>
<duration>2</duration>
</class>
<class>
<id>Test Data</id>
<title>Testing</title>
<description_url>Test Data</description_url>
<duration>2</duration>
</class>
<class>
<id>Test Data</id>
<title>Testing</title>
<description_url>Test Data</description_url>
<duration>2</duration>
</class>
</table>
```